# I can't get the code to say reached, anything I try to assign to the array position returns [] instead of the current state (index)

Tags: javascript, html

```
let level = 1

const buttonColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']

const gamePattern = []

const x = gamePattern.slice(gamePattern.length - 1, gamePattern.length)

function nextSequence () {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
  const randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber]
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor)

  console.log('The Current level: ' + level)

  $('#' + randomChosenColor).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100)
  playSound(randomChosenColor)

  if (level === 1) {
    $('#levelTitle').text('level ' + level)
  }
  level++
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

$('.btn').click(function () {
  const userChosenColor = this.id

  playSound(userChosenColor)
  animatePress(userChosenColor)
  checkAnswer(buttonColors.indexOf(userChosenColor))

  console.log('User chosen Color: ' + buttonColors.indexOf(userChosenColor)) // indexOf is not a string*
})
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

function animatePress (currentColor) {
  $('#' + currentColor).addClass('pressed')

  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#' + currentColor).removeClass('pressed')
  }, 100)
}

function playSound (name) {
  const audio = new Audio('sounds/' + name + '.mp3')
  audio.play()
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

function checkAnswer (currentLevelColor) { // indexOf #1 === indexOf #2
  if (currentLevelColor === buttonColors.indexOf(x)) {
    console.log('REACHED')
  } else {
    console.log('NOT REACHED')
  }
}

$(document).keydown(nextSequence)
```

I've been stuck trying to save the array as a variable but my browser never recognizes the code after I try to save it as a variable, but the code on it's own works. - I have tried various methods breaking the code down and restructuring it to no avail; can someone explain what I'm doing wrong - the goal is to get the code to say "REACHED" HTML BELOW*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> <!-- NOTE: CSS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="levelTitle">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="game.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML as well in a snippet

Comment: Hi, I added HTML to original document.

Comment: This is because when the html loads the game.js file it runs the code ones. When the code interprets, gamepattern is an empty array, hence, your constant x is always an empty array too. Move the code to where appropriate that requires to re-calibrate the value of x. Note that you cannot keep assigning x since it is a const.

Comment: Also, when console.log can have multiple parameters, so you don't have concatenate. Example: console.log('User chosen Color: ', buttonColors.indexOf(userChosenColor), userChosenColor). This way you can see the type of the variable as well as it's values. Comes really handy to know what you are dealing with.

Comment: Another, hick up would be the type of x is an array since the .slice returns an array. When checking if (currentLevelColor === buttonColors.indexOf(x)) would probably not behave as expected since you are trying to get the Array.indexOf(Array) instead of Array.indexOf(element).